# Converting from Js.Promise to `reason-promise` in ReasonML

Tags: promise, apollo-client, reason, bucklescript

I have a situation where a library is using [reason-promise](https://github.com/aantron/promise) as a default one branch and not another. I am finding it difficult to switch from one branch to another because I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to use reason-promise. I am not much better at Js.Promise but that is besides the point.

The library in question is [reason-apollo-client](https://github.com/reasonml-community/reason-apollo-client). The branch has a bunch of other improvements, includes `reason-promise` as the default `promise` implementation. That branch is the [next branch](https://github.com/reasonml-community/reason-apollo-clientt/tree/next).

By way of example, found at [reason-promise-question](https://github.com/idkjs/reason-promise-question/blob/master/src/ClientPromiseExample.re), I have a `Js.Promise` function that gets me the current token value. It has the following type:

```ml
unit => Js.Promise.t(
  Js.Nullable.t(string)
)
```

The function can be found in [Tokens](https://github.com/idkjs/reason-promise-question/blob/master/src/Tokens.re) and is reproduced below. This is a dummy function, there is no binding. The point is to see how to get it to compile.

```ml
[@bs.val] [@bs.scope "localStorage"]
external setItem: (string, string) => unit = "setItem";
let setUserToken: string => Js.Promise.t(unit) =
  token => Js.Promise.resolve(setItem("auth", token));

[@bs.val] [@bs.scope "localStorage"]
external getItem: string => Js.Nullable.t(string) = "getItem";
let getUserToken: unit => Js.Promise.t(Js.Nullable.t(string)) =
  () => Js.Promise.resolve(getItem("auth"));

let setTempUserToken: string => Js.Promise.t(unit) =
  _ => Js.Promise.resolve();

let getTempUserToken: unit => Js.Promise.t(Js.Nullable.t(string)) =
  () => Js.Promise.resolve(Js.Nullable.undefined);
```

When I try use this with `reason-promise` when creating an `apollo/client` `authlink`, I get the following error:

```ml
unit => Js.Promise.t(
  Js.Nullable.t(string)
)
Error: This expression has type
         Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t) = Js.Promise.t(Js.Json.t)
       but an expression was expected of type
         Promise.t(Js.Json.t) = Promise.rejectable(Js.Json.t, Promise.never)
```

Here is the `authlink` function:

```ml
let authLink =
  ApolloClient.Link.ContextLink.makeAsync((~operation as _, ~prevContext as ctx) => {
    Tokens.getUserToken()
    ->Js.Promise.then_(
        token => {
          switch (token->Js.Nullable.toOption) {
          | None =>
            Tokens.getTempUserToken()
            ->Js.Promise.then_(
                token => Js.Promise.resolve(Js.Nullable.toOption(token)),
                _,
              )
          | Some(token) => Js.Promise.resolve(Some(token))
          }
        },
        _,
      )
    ->Js.Promise.then_(
        fun
        | None => Js.Promise.resolve(Js.Json.null)
        | Some(token) => {
            Js.Promise.resolve(
              [%raw
                {| (context, token) => ({
                headers: {
                  ...ctx.headers,
                  authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
              }) |}
              ](
                ctx,
                token,
              ),
            );
          },
        _,
      )
  });
```

How do we convert this to a reason-promise? Please feel free to be as diadactic as you want to be.

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to convert your vanilla `Js.Promise.t` into a `Promise.t`.

First, you will have to convert your `Js.Promise.t` into a `Promise.Js.t`. This can be done by

```
let myIntermediatePromise = myJsPromise |>  Promise.Js.fromBsPromise
```

The reason that the extra `Promise.Js.t` type exists is because of the difference in the philosophy of error handling between `Js.Promise.t` and `Promise.t`. The latter, handles errors using the `Belt.Result` module (as seen on https://github.com/aantron/promise#handling-errors-with-result) whereas the former uses rejection (which is typically handled with `catch` (in JavaScript) or `catch_` (in Reason)). The intermediate product of `Promise.Js.t` encapsulates the same philosophy as the JavaScript promise.

In order to convert the intermediate product to the final `Promise.t`, you will therefore need to explicitly indicate what should happen when/if the intermediate promise gets rejected. This can be done with a few different ways but as an example you can do:

```
let myFinalPromise = myIntermediatePromise |> Promise.Js.toResult
```

This will convert your original `Js.Promise.t('a)` into a `Promise.t(Result('a, Js.Promise.error))`.

If you'd like to further convert to `Promise.t('a)`, you have to explicitly handle the possible error.

See https://github.com/aantron/promise#advanced-rejection for more details.

NB that it looks like apollo has since moved to using vanilla promises (https://github.com/reasonml-community/reason-apollo-client/pull/57).